# How To Add Basic Authentication To HTTP Request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have always used RestSharp - but this project requires HttpClient.  How would I add basic auth to this?

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPost);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var url = "";
using var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Check if the solution at this link helps you: https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below implementation -

```
 using var client = new HttpClient();
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Please mark if this answer is usful.

Comment: if you want to try this code, the variable url and data are defined in the question above. re-posted below: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPost);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var url = "";

Answer (score 0):

Add an Authorization header.

Authorization: Basic <"user:pass" encoded to base64>